# Tensor of quotients question

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modules, tensor-products

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be the 1-variable polynomial ring over the the integers, $q$ and $p$ arbitrary prime numbers, $R_1 = \mathbb{Z}[[x]]/(p)$, and $R_2 = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(q, x)$.

> Question: what is $Q: = R_1 \otimes_R R_2$?

Intuitively, I think $Q = \mathbb{Z}[x]/((p)+(q,x))$. Geometrically, it's as if we are intersecting two closed subvarieties of $\rm{Spec}\; \mathbb{Z}[[x]].$

Thoughts?

Comment: and what about replacing $R_2$ with $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(q,x^e)$ for some integer $e\geq 1$? (nilpotents)

Comment: $\;R_2\;$ is a field, and $\;R_1\;$ seems to be an integer domain (take a peek at http://math.aa.psu.edu/~juan/papers/ufdPower.pdf) ...perhaps this can help a little.

Comment: $R_1\cong F_p[[x]]$ and $R_2\cong F_q$. $\Bbb Z[x]/((p+(q,x)))$ is $\{0\}$ if $p\neq q$, and $F_p[x]$ if $p=q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes then $Q = 0$ because as you will have $p(1 \otimes 1)=p \otimes 1 = 0= 1 \otimes q = q(1 \otimes 1)$.  This means that the prime ring of $Q$ is $0$.

If $p=q$ then $Q=\mathbb{Z}[[x]]/(p,x^e) = (\mathbb{Z}/p)[x]/(x^e)$.

Comment: ok, thank you. and if $R_2$ is replaced by $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(q, x^e)$? seems then the tensor product with $R_1$ is trivial or $\oplus_{i=1}^e \mathbb{Z}/p$?